# Safari HTML5 offline problem

Tags: html, safari, offline

I am trying to run a script that supports for HTML5 offline working.  It works fine in Firefox but not in safari.  I want it to work in safari too. You can see here.

http://vps.sunztech.com/clock.html

HOW TO CHECK OFFLINE WORKING: open the URL when internet is connected.close the browser after loading all contents. now disable internet and load that URL again it should show the the data from cache.

The above is working fine in Firefox but not in Safari.

May anyone can give me the solution...

I will be thankful

Comment: How have you enabled/implemented offline capabilities? Isn't it that Firefox is picking the content from cache and Safari is just skipping that cached data?

Comment: See this link http://cachemanifest.heroku.com/ it is working in firefox and also in safari. with the the default settings. but when i want to let my code work it does not work in safari.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the manifest file is served as type `text/cache-manifest`. There are several other guidelines worth checking in [Apple's developer documentation for iPhone and Mobile Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html).